# TFLite Interpreter fails to load quantized model on Android

Tags: android, android-studio, tensorflow, quantization, tensorflow-lite

I have a TFLite model. The model input is a 256x192 image, it is quantized to 16 bit. It was quantized with this converter:

```py
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
converter.target_spec.supported_types = [tf.float16]
tflite_model = converter.convert()
```

I am trying to load it in my android app, and faces the following problem, while executing `tflite = new Interpreter(tfliteModel, tfliteOptions);`:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: CameraBackground
    Process: android.example.com.tflitecamerademo, PID: 7943
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Internal error: Cannot create interpreter: Unimplemented data type FLOAT16 (1) in tensor
    Unimplemented data type FLOAT16 (1) in tensor
```

What can I try in order to solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Looks like you should use tf.float16 starting tf 2
https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/1x_compatibility#unsupported_apis

May be file an issue on [github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/new?labels=type%3Abug&template=00-bug-issue.md)